# PHP Get new content when caching headers change and content has expired

Tags: php, caching, header

I'm having a bit of confusion over how to handle this caching scenario.

The user visits a page that initially should be cached. So I set the headers using php ...

```
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 86400) . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=86400");
header("Pragma: cache");
```

This works fine. The user's browser loads the page from cache each time they visit it. I've only tested this in Chrome - it obeys the headers and all is well.

But then I change some content on the page. I want the new content that's been added to also be displayed the next time the user visits the page. I've tried setting the headers to tell the browser not to load the page from cache but to get it from the server. The headers look like this ...

```
header("Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

But the browser still gets the content from it's cache. It seems like the browser is remembering the old headers and continues to obey the instructions it was given, which I guess is the expected behaviour. But the problem is that it's not getting the new headers and discovering that the content has now expired.

How do I tell the browser that the content has now expired?

Comment: Once a page is cached it won't get fresh copy unless cache expires or your manually get rid of it (using hard refresh).

Comment: By setting those caching headers you are telling the world "don't bother checking for changes until at least tomorrow". There is literally no way for you to change what you've already told the world because you've already told them not to even ask. You need to better consider your caching strategy.

Comment: I think you might be right about rethinking the strategy